# Choosing unique names for luaL_newmetatable

Tags: lua

I'm writing a Lua library which registers some metatables using `luaL_newmetatable()`. Since other libraries might do that as well, I'd like to ask what is a good strategy to avoid having the same name used twice. I was thinking about using a reverse DNS name like `com.mydomain.mylibrary` which should be pretty safe I guess. However, I'd like to ask if there maybe is a better or standard way of choosing unique names for libraries using `luaL_newmetatable()`.

Comment: Use [GUIDs](https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx) whenever you need unique string (not human-readable though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like use lightuserdata with pointer to string.

```
#define LCURL_EASY_NAME LCURL_PREFIX" Easy"
static const char *LCURL_EASY = LCURL_EASY_NAME;
```

It just requires simple functions to use it.

```
int lutil_newmetatablep (lua_State *L, const void *p) {
  lua_rawgetp(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, p);
  if (!lua_isnil(L, -1))
    return 0;
  lua_pop(L, 1);

  lua_newtable(L);  /* create metatable */
  lua_pushvalue(L, -1); /* duplicate metatable to set*/
  lua_rawsetp(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, p);

  return 1;
}
```

Similar for get/set. Checkout e.g. my [Lua-cURL](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3/blob/master/src/l52util.c#L63) library.

Comment: Why not using pointer to byte (reserved but not initialized variable of size 1 byte) to save memory? Do you use this string pointer for other purposes except creating a light userdata? For example, do you use this string for identifying?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a string that describes what is in the "object" as this string is output in Lua error message eventually:

e.g. if the metatable is named "database connection":

stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'status' (database connection expected, got no value)

If you use a UUID, nobody can make sense of the output.

Comment: And how to avoid metatable name collisions? Other developer may use the same word for his own metatable.  That is what OP asks about.

Comment: I have not tried it, but maybe a string with an embedded NUL character could be used:  "database connection\0x00<eg. a uuid>".  I guess the error message will only contain the bytes up until the NUL character

Comment: I just tried it, it actually works.  Just not sure if the string is alread stripped when creating the metatable or when the output happens...

Comment: maybe better to prefix the metatable name with the name of the Lua module, e.g. "pgsql database connection".